# Silverlight Controls

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

Where can I find free silverlight controls with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Telerik Silverlight Controls: http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight.aspx (my personal favorite) - Sorry, I just noticed you said "free"

Microsoft Silverlight Toolkit: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: thanks looked at both of those.

Comment: +1 for the Silverlight Toolkit

Comment: @Scrappydog: where was your +1? Mine was the first +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You also can look on 
[codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/) and 
[codeplex.com](http://www.codeplex.com/).
There are lot of free and very nice controls.

Answer (score 0):

**[Vectorlight](http://www.vectorlight.net/controls.aspx)** has a lot of free controls:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains a list of SL controls providers:

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/01/28/comprehensive-list-of-silverlight-controls.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check for BlackLight. They have some neat ones.

http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/